# React-Apollo handling error with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I am building a react native app with react-apollo. I can't handle graphql error. I have tried some ways but it doesn't work. How can I catch graphql errors?
Here is my code;

```
export default compose(
  graphql(UpdateCounter, {
    options: {
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
    },
    props: (props) => ({
      appSyncUpdateCounter: (post) => {
        props.mutate({
          variables: post,
          optimisticResponse: () => console.log('...'),
          update: (cache, mutationResult) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(mutationResult, null, 2));
            if (mutationResult.data.updateCounter) {
              console.log(mutationResult.data.updateCounter);
            }
          },
        }).catch((e) => { console.log(e.graphQLErrors); });
      }
    }),
  }),
)(Counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wrapping the Counter component it needs to call and catch that promise. Additionally, I would use react-apollos new Mutation component and simply wrap it in an `<ErrorBoundary />`. It would replace the need for the above code.